# C#/NHibernate: Association references unmapped class: MvcApplication7.Models.Comments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I cant figure out why Am I getting this error:
Association references unmapped class: MvcApplication7.Models.Comments.
Please note : One Post can have many Comments(One to Many relationship)

Im very new to all these technologies. Could you also tell me what Ive done is correct?

---

```
        namespace MvcApplication7.Models
        {
            public class Posts
            {
                public virtual int Id { get; set; }
                public virtual int PostId { get; set; }
                public virtual string Post { get; set; }

            }

        }

    ********************************************************************

        namespace MvcApplication7.Models
        {
            public class Comments
            {
                 public virtual int CommentId { get; set; }
                 public virtual int PostId { get; set; }
                 public virtual string Comment { get; set; }
            }
        }

    ********************************************************************

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" assembly="MvcApplication7" namespace="MvcApplication7.Models">

          <class name="Posts" table="Posts" dynamic-update="true" >
            <cache usage="read-write"/>
            <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
              <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">posts_id_seq</param>
              </generator>
            </id>

            <property name="Post" column="Post"/>

            <set name="PostId" inverse="true" lazy="true" >
              <key column="PostId"/>
              <one-to-many class="Comments"/>
            </set>

          </class>
        </hibernate-mapping>

    ********************************************************************

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" assembly="MvcApplication7" namespace="MvcApplication7.Models">

          <class name="Comments" table="Comments" dynamic-update="true" >
            <cache usage="read-write"/>

            <id name="CommentId" column="CommentId" type="int">
              <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">comments_commentid_seq</param>
              </generator>
            </id>

            <property name="Comment" column="Comment"/>

            <many-to-one name="Post" class="MvcApplication7.Models.Posts" column="Id"></many-to-one>

          </class>
        </hibernate-mapping>
*****************************************************************************
```

The Followings are my tables in PostgraSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE comments
(
  commentid serial NOT NULL,
  postid integer,
  comment text,
  CONSTRAINT commentid PRIMARY KEY (commentid),
  CONSTRAINT postid FOREIGN KEY (postid)
      REFERENCES posts (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE comments
  OWNER TO postgres;
*********************************************************
CREATE TABLE posts
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  post text,
  CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE posts
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Try  <one-to-many class="MvcApplication7.Models.Comments"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow your DB design, these should be the entities:

```
public class Post
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostText { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
     public virtual string CommentText { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping

```
  <class name="Post" table="Posts" dynamic-update="true" >
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">posts_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="PostText" column="Post"/>

    <bag name="Comments" inverse="true" lazy="true" >
      <key column="PostId"/>
      <one-to-many class="Comment"/>
    </bag>

  </class>



  <class name="Comment" table="Comments" dynamic-update="true" >
    <cache usage="read-write"/>

    <id name="Id" column="CommentId" type="int">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">comments_commentid_seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

    <property name="CommentText" column="Comment"/>

    <many-to-one name="Post" class="Post" column="PostId" />

  </class>
```

So, we are using singular form name Comment for each comment and Post for each post

Also Post has collection of these Comments. They are mapped as one-to-many via column PostId in Comments table. The same column is used for many-to-one mapping of the `Post` property (parent) on the Comment. Do not forget to set both relations if you create the Comment

```
Post post = ...
Comment comment = new Comment() ...
post.Comments.Add(comment);
comment.Post = post;
```

This is a must for inverse mapping

For sure do go through these:

[Chapter 21. Example: Parent/Child](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild)

Comment: Do you mean PostId instead of Post in this class: public class Comment
{
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }
     public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
     public virtual string CommentText { get; set; }
}  @Radim Köhler

Comment: No - I mean we need a `Post` property instead of PostId! We need a reference to be mapped! I also would suggest to use Post... not Posts. Does it help? Also, I did not rename Posts... to Post previously. So I updated the answer.

Comment: Ok,Thank you, I understand what you mean now. I just try this and will let you know. Thanks again. @Radim Köhler

Comment: Great, let me know. NHibernate is great tool, so we should make it :)

Comment: I did exactly as you said, In fact I copy pasted your code and I'm getting this error now: Association references unmapped class: MvcApplication7.Models.Comment.The error is from this page:Post.hbm.xml @Radim Köhler

Comment: Suggestion - place both mapping into Post.hbm.xml. Why? It seems that your second mapping was not found. Could be missing .hbm.xml suffix or is not an embedded resource. So, place it for now to Post.hbm.xml (because we know that it is correctly found)

Comment: Great, It works nows, Thanks alot, I'm now trying to test the create and update. @Radim Köhler

Comment: Awesome. I guess we are done. If'll have other issues later, do not hesitate to ask other question. Good luck with NHibernate.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so clearly. @Radim Köhler

Comment: I have posted a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868123/update-foreign-key-using-asp-net-mvc-and-nhibernate?noredirect=1#comment40479898_25868123). Can you have a look at it please?